# Java compile error: "reached end of file while parsing }"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have the following source code

```
public class mod_MyMod extends BaseMod
public String Version()
{
     return "1.2_02";
}
public void AddRecipes(CraftingManager recipes)
{
   recipes.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Item.diamond), new Object[] {
      "#", Character.valueOf('#'), Block.dirt
   });
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
java:11: reached end of file while parsing }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're getting the error because you're missing a pair of braces.  Look carefully at the class.

Answer (score 32):

You have to open and close your class with `{ ... }` like:

```
public class mod_MyMod extends BaseMod
{
  public String Version()
  {
    return "1.2_02";
  }

  public void AddRecipes(CraftingManager recipes)
  {
     recipes.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Item.diamond), new Object[] {
        "#", Character.valueOf('#'), Block.dirt });
  }
}
```

Comment: one reason could be single line comments outside of class brackets... that  is what I faced

Answer (score 11):

You need to enclose your class in `{` and `}`. A few extra pointers: According to the Java coding conventions, you should

- Put your `{` on the same line as the method declaration:
- Name your classes using CamelCase (with initial capital letter)
- Name your methods using camelCase (with small initial letter)

Here's how I would write it:

```
public class ModMyMod extends BaseMod {

    public String version() {
         return "1.2_02";
    }

    public void addRecipes(CraftingManager recipes) {
       recipes.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Item.diamond), new Object[] {
          "#", Character.valueOf('#'), Block.dirt
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It happens when you don't properly close the code block:

```
if (condition){
  // your code goes here*
  { // This doesn't close the code block
```

Correct way:

```
if (condition){
  // your code goes here
} // Close the code block
```

Comment: How is that different from other earlier answers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You were missing a '{' under the public class line. And then one at the end of your code to close it.