# Reached end of file while parsing error

Tags: java, parsing, compilation

I created this code in Java but I am getting the following error: 
"Reached end of file while parsing error". 
Can someone please have a look at it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ParseTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Set<String> positive = loadDictionary("PositiveWordsDictionary");
    Set<String> negative = loadDictionary("NegativeWordsDictionary");

    File file = new File("fileforparsing");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
    String word;
    long positiveCount = 0;
    long negativeCount = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        word = sc.next();
        if (positive.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println("Found positive "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            positiveCount++;
        }
        if (negative.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println("Found negative "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            negativeCount++;
        }
    }
    br.close();
}



public static Set<String> loadDictionary(String fileName) throws IOException {

    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        words.add(sc.next());
    }
    br.close();
    return words;

}
```

I have checked the curly braces error but nothing helps.

Comment: Add a `}` at the end. Seems to be missing.

Comment: You're missing one more closing curly brace... Check again `}` A better indented code might help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java compile error: "reached end of file while parsing }"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934412/java-compile-error-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace.  This is what your code should look like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ParseTest
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Set<String> positive = loadDictionary("PositiveWordsDictionary");
    Set<String> negative = loadDictionary("NegativeWordsDictionary");

    File file = new File("fileforparsing");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
    String word;
    long positiveCount = 0;
    long negativeCount = 0;

    while (sc.hasNext())
        {
        word = sc.next();
        if (positive.contains(word))
            {
            System.out.println("Found positive "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            positiveCount++;
            }
        if (negative.contains(word))
            {
            System.out.println("Found negative "+positiveCount+":"+word);
            negativeCount++;
            }
         }
    br.close();
}



public static Set<String> loadDictionary(String fileName) throws IOException
{

    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);

    while (sc.hasNext())
        {
        words.add(sc.next());
        }
    br.close();

    return words;
}
}
```

Line up your brackets, makes it much easier to read.