# What is the "reached end of file while parsing" error, and how can I avoid this error in the future?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My question is very simple. I am just wondering what the reached end of file while parsing error actually means / is. Why this error actually occurs. In addition, how I could avoid it. Before you say that this is a duplication of question it really isn't because most questions I looked at are just examples with code. That is not what I am looking for I am just looking for a clear cut answer of why this error happens what it is / means, and how to avoid it that is it.

NOTE: I don't understand "reached the end of the file". I know what parsing is, but I don't know what it means by reached the end of file:               while parsing. I also just want to now how to avoid this error, and why it occurs not just to understand it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934412/java-compile-error-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing

Comment: If you read the question, I literally state how this is not a duplicate of those question as though questions adress code for something with that error. Not just the error, itself

Comment: What specific part of **reached the end of file** are you having problems understanding? Do you understand what **end of file** means? Do you understand what **reached** (as in **we've reached our destination**) means? Put them together: **reached (as in arrived at) the end of the file**, which means **there's no more file to read**.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't understand reached the end of the file. I know what parsing is, but I don't know what it means by reached the end of file:               while parsing. I also just want to now how to avoid this error, and why it occurs not just to understan it.

Comment: It means that it "Reached the end of file while parsing", i.e. the parsing is incomplete, but there is no more text to parse. Example: Expression `a * (2 + b` is incomplete, because it's missing a `)`. What's not to understand about that? It reached the end of input (aka "the file") at a time when more text is required (aka "while parsing").

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry I didn't realize that because. It doesn't look like an expression is incomplete. a * (2 + b would give you this error it would give you something like illegal expression

Comment: *"It doesn't look like an expression is incomplete"* Well, **something** in whatever it is you're parsing is incomplete (unbalanced `()`, `{}`, `[]`, `""`, `''`, or the like). Since you're asking a *generic* question, not the *specific* question required by StackOverflow, we can't help you with *what* is actually wrong.

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry, but I've already been helped. Please see the answer that is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid this error by fixing the syntax in the code causing the parser to expect additional closing syntax indicators (like a right curly-brace).  Also check the responses to the duplicate questions because they clearly explain what are generally the syntactical causes of same error.

Comment: Thank you this a good and valid answer, I actually realized that the probably in my code was that I was missing a curly brace actually in my code that you very much.

Comment: I will accept your answer when I am able to in 5 minutes